# Transparent bridge over 802.11 and ethernet

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

I have a computer running Debian Linux attached to a **WLAN** network and I need to bridge its **ethernet** interface to in order to provide network functionality to another computer  connected to the ethernet port.

I want the computer to be visible to my WLAN network with it's own **IP** and **MAC address**. In other words I think that this is called transparent bridge.

While I looked around I found that this [can not be implemented](https://serverfault.com/questions/152363/bridging-wlan0-to-eth0) but I noticed that this can easily happen when I [bridge my VirtualBox interfaces](https://superuser.com/questions/594550/how-does-bridged-networking-work-in-virtualbox) with my WLAN interface.

Is there really no solution to the problem but only VirtualBox has figured it out? Where can I find more info in such networking features for Linux?

Comment: well, you are looking at an answer from 2010. Additionally the answer indicates that it is the hardware mode available to the NIC (Station Mode not AP Mode) that is the problem, so entirely unlike the Vbox issue. If you can put your wifi nic into AP mode, you may have a different set of options available. This makes sense, since in STA mode, the upstream AP would only send traffic destined for the debian box, never traffic destined for the clients downstream of the bridge.

Comment: You simply cannot have a transparent bridge between 802.3 (ethernet) and 802.11 (Wi-Fi) since the layer-2 frames are incompatible. You _can_, however, have a translating bridge which is what a WAP does. You _must_ translate frames from 802.3 to 802.11 (or 802.4, 802.5, etc.).

Comment: @FrankThomas Virtualbox does what I ask transparently for virtual guest network adapters so there must be a way to trick my kernel doing it for physical adapters as well.

Comment: @RonMaupin Do you know if there are any software tools for the linux kernel that do the job you describe? I'm new to networking and I am a bit puzzled.