# Doubts on Mac address of Guest OS configured in bridged mode

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, bridge, arp

I'm running Kali ( guest OS ) in workstation pro. My host OS is windows 10. Guest OS is configured in Bridged networking mode.

Consider the following parameters of :-

```
Guest OS - IP_G:MAC_G

Host OS - IP_H:MAC_H
```

ARP table of :-

```
Guest OS - IP_H:MAC_H ( perfect )

Host OS - IP_G:MAC_G ( perfect )

Another Host ( within the same network as Host OS ) - IP_H:MAC_H ( perfect ) , IP_G:MAC_H ( why? )
```

why does another host have the mac address associated to IP_G as MAC_H ? shouldn't it be MAC_G?

Also My guest OS doesn't show up in the router's connected devices, is it because the Guest OS didn't actually authenticate and associate with the router as explained in this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/594550/how-does-bridged-networking-work-in-virtualbox)? or is there any other reason?

Comment: If the hosts NIC is a WiFi adapter, this might be the cause. Briding seems to have troubles sending different MACs over WiFi adapters.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) why does another host have the mac address associated to IP_G as
> MAC_H ? shouldn't it be MAC_G?

VMware Workstation tries to maintain the Host Network Adapter MAC address but it does not always work.

The Guest MAC address can be changed in the the VMware Advanced Networking tool.

Probably the best thing is to let VMware assign MAC addresses and not try to change them.

[Change Guest MAC address](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-5C55C285-79B0-404F-95A5-87F64C41E3DC.html)

> Select the virtual machine and select VM > Settings. On the Hardware
> tab, select the virtual network adapter and click Advanced. Type a new
> MAC address in the MAC Address text box, or click Generate to have
> Workstation Pro generate a new address. Click OK to save your changes.

========

> (2) Also My guest OS doesn't show up in the router's connected
> devices, is it because the Guest OS didn't actually authenticate and
> associate with the router

The default connection in VMware Workstation is NAT and so the DHCP server is internal to the machine and only the Host machine shows up in the Router. You can use Bridged Networking if you wish the Guest to get a Router IP address.

Comment: I'm already networked in bridged mode, i do not wish for the guest oS to get a router IP address, but rather i wished to see the guest OS in the router's associated device ?

Comment: A router sees a VMware virtual machine in bridged mode the same way it sees a real machine. So bridged mode will work as a normal network setup. You will need to see if NAT will fulfill your needs.